# username and password to url in python selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-webdriver-python

**Introduction**:

i am doing UI testing with python and selenium and i am blocked when sign in page is asked as pop up window and i only seen best way is to pass the username and password to the url.. but my username contains "@" and "*" i even tried with encoded version of it still its not working

**Problem:**

```
normal url - driver.get("https://firstname.lastname@test.com:testpass*11@test.company.com")
encoded -    driver.get("https://firstname.lastname%40test.com:testpass%2A11@test.company.com")
```

i used **'%40'** for **'@'** and **'%2A'** for **'*'** ,

**Error:**

Getting error like 404

Comment: Does it work when using the same url‘s directly in the browser?

Comment: yeah closing this .. since i used wrong url